# Short term savings

Tags: savings, eur-euro, european-union, short-term

I want to save about €1500 ($2000) in 5-7 months and then take out the money and buy something specific. There is a pretty low probability that I should need some of it during the first 4 months, but after that, I'll need it available within 2 weeks of asking for them. What are my options?

I'm a student working part-time, have no debt and live in Czech republic. I also wonder if the savings account (or anything else) should be in [Czech crowns](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=czech+crown) or in euro (in Slovakia, where I come from), since I get money in both of them (about 40% in €) and there is a higher probability that I will make my purchase in euro.

Comment: Added some tags for you.

Comment: $2000 is chump change I'd just buy it now

Comment: @WillDen I'm not willing to get into debt. This is a lot of money in my country. But I guess you're just trolling.

Comment: Not trolling just trying to give perspective. Life is too short to worry about a few thousand dollars

Comment: Seriously, even over the longer term $2000 is not a lot of money to invest. $20 transaction fees would be 1% of your balance. That's a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For such a short timeframe, I'd have it in the currency (euros) you need, and in a savings account. The 5 months is not a time to 'invest' this money. Even 2-4 years would suggest just a CD or short term Government bond.